# How to get count of downloads of an android app

Tags: android, google-play, web-scraping

I'm crawling and scraping android market Web site.

But I cannot get count of downloads of apps from the Web site
because it doesn't provide information about downloads though it provides ranking.

So, does anyone know how to get the count of downloads?

Comment: I am trying to do the same. Are you able to get actual no of downloads?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do it in 2 steps:

1. Get list of all app ids in first step
2. Get details for each app id through https://market.android.com/details?id=com.xyz.uvw etc. (In the details page there is "INSTALLS" which gives the range for total number of installs)

Comment: Thank you. So, how can I get not the range but the exact number?

Comment: IMHO there is no way to get exact number, you can also refer to this link- http://www.androlib.com/appstats.aspx which has a feature called ESTIMATE which may give approximate downloads